# Flutter - wait a Future Json to load another Json

Tags: json, dart, flutter, future

i want to wait a json load to do another one in the same screen,
like that:

```
new CustomScrollView(
          cacheExtent: height * 6,
            slivers: [
              new SliverList(
                  delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      new RelatorioVendPeriodoAPeriodo(), //after it loads do \/(RelatorioVendasTotalidasPorPeriodo)
                      new RelatorioVendasTotalidasPorPeriodo(), //after it loads do \/(RelatorioDasVendasTotsProdutos)
                      new RelatorioDasVendasTotsProdutos(), //after it loads do \/(RelatorioMensals)
                      new RelatorioMensals(),

                    ]
                  )
              )
            ]
        ),
```

I was thinking in FutureBuilder, or Future.delayed but it isn't working well.

Thanks.